# Gold or silver badge for multiple daily votes

Tags: feature-request, badges, voting, badge-request

There is a badge for using 30 votes (Suffrage) in a day.  There is also a badge (Vox Populi) for using the maximum 40 votes in a day.  However, there are no badges for doing either of these multiple times.

What I am suggesting implementing a silver badge for using 30 votes in a day 100 times and a gold badge for using 30 votes in a day 300 times.

It has frequently been my observation that people tend to get the Vox Populi and Suffrage badges and then just kind of slack off of voting.  It would be substantially beneficial to the community if people were out trying to get more voting badges.

And yes, there are definitely people who spend enough time on some of the stacks to warrant getting a badge for 30 votes 300 times ***without randomly voting up whatever material comes to mouse.***

Comment: The title and the body do not match. Title says you want badge for "reps", i.e. gaining reputation, body says you want it for voting. Please decide what you really want, and fix the proper part of the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, thank you so much for pointing that out!  Fixed.

Comment: Well, so this is no doubt a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are already two other badges that promote voting, beyond Suffrage and Vox Populi: [Civic Duty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) and [Electorate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/electorate). IMHO, the proposed badges do not promote good behaviour anymore than the current badges do.

Note that the purpose of [bronze badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-are-badges) like Suffrage and Vox Populi is not *only* to encourage voting, but also to make people aware of the existence daily vote limit, and (in the Vox Populi case) that voting on questions is at least as important as voting on answers.

My personal feeling is that these badges will encourage some people to go on a voting spree, handing out votes without paying too much attention to the actual content.